# Skia Decoder fails to decode remote Stream

Tags: android, imageview, skia

I am trying to open a remote Stream of a JPEG image and convert it into a Bitmap object:

```
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
new URL("http://some.url.to/source/image.jpg")
.openStream());
```

The decoder returns null and in the logs I get the following message:

```
DEBUG/skia(xxxx): --- decoder->decode returned false
```

Note:
1. the content length is non-zero and content type is `image/jpeg`
2. When I open the URL in browser I can see the image.

What is that I am missing here?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide a link to an image that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately, i cant. I understand what you are indirectly hinting to here... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems there was some problem with the stream and the way android handled it; the patch in this [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066) solved the problem for now.

Answer (score 10):

The solution provided in [android bug n°6066](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066) consist in overriding the std FilterInputStream and then send it to the BitmapFactory.

```
static class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                  int byteValue = read();
                  if (byteValue < 0) {
                      break;  // we reached EOF
                  } else {
                      bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                  }
           }
           totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

and then use the decodeStream function:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(inputStream));
```

---

The other solution i've found is to simply give a BufferedInputStream to th BitmapFactory:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream));
```

These two solutions should do the trick.

More information can be found in the bug report comments : [android bug no.6066](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6066)

Comment: FWIW the FlushedInputStream method worked for me; the BufferedInputStream did not. Also, "byte" is a reserved keyword, so you should change "int byte" to "int byteValue" or something.

Comment: This bug is still not fixed and the workarounds don't always work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem is with type of color of image: your image are in color= CYMK not in RGB

Answer (score 0):

I have found a library, which can open images on which Android SKIA fails. It can be useful for certain usecases:

https://github.com/suckgamony/RapidDecoder

For me it solved the problem as I am not loading many images at once and lot of images I load have ICC profile.
I haven't tried integrating it with some common libraries like Picasso or Glide.